# Get result collection of two child tables joined by one parent table in linq

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have 3 entities: `Surveys`, `Batch`, and `Removed`where Surveys is the parent table and the other two are related to Surveys with foreign keys.

```
public class Surveys
{
    public int TireID { get; set; }
    public dateTime DateCreated{ get; set; }
}
public class Batch
{
    public int TireID { get; set; }
    public int TirePosition{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<Surveys> Survey{ get; set; }
}
public class Removed
{
    public int TireID { get; set; }
    public int TirePosition{ get; set; }
    public dateTime DateRemoved{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<Surveys> Survey{ get; set; }
}
```

I have a query to get the Batch of tires that formed part of the Survey, and the removed ones from Removed:

```
var surveys = ctx.Surveys.Where(a => a.DateSubmitted >= startDate && a.DateSubmitted < endDate).Select(a => new T_Batch
{
    //don't know how to get desired result
}).ToList();
```

I have a custom type that the query result (T_Batch) should be of:

```
public class T_Batch
{
    public int TireID { get; set; }
    public int TirePosition { get; 
    public T_Removed Removed{ get; set; }
}
public class T_Removed
{
    public int TireID { get; set; }
    public int TirePosition { get; set; }
}
```

The query result brings back a list of Surveys which is fine, but I would like a list of tires per Survey list item, and a removed tire (if there was one removed) per tire position. I don't know how to achieve this.

Example of desired result:

```
    0 Batch_Tire1
    1 Batch_Tire2
        0 Removed_Tire
    2 Batch_Tire3
    3 Batch_Tire4
        0 Removed_Tire
 etc...
```

**UPDATE**

I could do something like this, but I need to get the result set as my custom type.

```
var surveys = ctx.TM_Survey.Where(a => a.DateSubmitted >= startDate && a.DateSubmitted < endDate).Select(a => new
{
    BatchItem = a.Batch,
    RemovedItem = a.Removed
}).ToList();
```

**UPDATE 2**

Or I could do this, but the result only returns a limited number of rows equal to the number of keys in `TM_Survey`

```
var surveys = ctx.TM_Survey.Where(a => a.DateSubmitted >= startDate && a.DateSubmitted < endDate).Select(a => new T_Batch
{
    TireID = a.T_Batch.Select(b => b.ID).First(),
    TirePosition = a.T_Batch.Select(b => b.TirePosition).First()
    Removed = new T_Removed 
    { 
      //...etc 
    }
}).ToList();
```

Comment: And what is the problem with setting it as a custom type?

Comment: I don't understand that question. I want it as a custom type but when I do so, I don't get the entire collection in the lambda expression 'a'. I'm sure there must be a cleaner way than to create loops inside of loops to retrieve and group things.

Comment: Can you show the type of `Survey`? e.g. what is `a.Batch` and what is `a.Removed`?

Comment: @Netmage Updated as requested

Comment: I don't see `TirePosition` in any of the source classes? I don't see any reference to `Batch` or `Removed` in your sample query? What is the type of Survey1 in your answer picture? Can you show actual data types for the answer?

Comment: @NetMage Thanks, I fixed the `TirePosition`. You don't see `Batch` or `Removed` because I don't know how to use them to produce the required result. I need a list of `T_Batch`. Survey1 was just example. I updated that too.

Comment: In update 2, you have `a` as from `TM_Survey` so I assume of type `Surveys` but you reference `a.T_Batch` which isn't in your definition of `Surveys`. Where did `T_Batch` come from? Are you using Entity Framework with navigation properties?

Comment: @NetMage Yes, exactly

Comment: Then can you correct the `Surveys` definition to include all properties?

Comment: @NetMage The navigation properties for `Survey` are in the `Batch` and `Removed` entities. The `T_Batch` and `T_Removed` classes are just the types I need the result of the query from the entities to be.

Comment: A navigation property would be of type `ICollection`. I don't see those. I also still don't see a definition for `a.T_Batch` in update 2. Where is `a.T_Batch` defined?

Comment: @NetMage T_Batch is my custom type already defined.

Comment: And `a.T_Batch` is not a type but a field or property, presumably of `ctx.TM_Survey` and I still don't see it defined. Assuming `TM_Survey` and `Surveys` is the same and not different, it isn't in the `Survey` class definition.